# Node.js: Get original object name

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, electron, filenames

I modelled a surface in a CAD program, gave it a certain name (e.g. **surface1**) and locally saved this surface with a specific name on my desktop (e.g. filename = **surf** or **apple** or **...**).

Now I write an application where I want to upload/post a larger number of such **surf**-files on a website. Via a *SaveFileDialog* I can choose the required files and upload them.

The files are imported as follows:
`var filename = dialog.showOpenDialog(options);`

The files are served for the public webserver as follows:

```
[...]
.then(async function (data) {
            token = data.id_token;
            let formData = new FormData;
            formData.append('file', new Blob([fs.readFileSync(filename.toString())]), filename.toString().split("/").pop());
            let response = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
                    "Authorization": " Bearer " + token
                },
                body: formData
            });
            return response;
```

The problem: For some filter routine I need the original object or surface name, like it was chosen in the CAD program (**surface1**). When I want to work with the variable *filename*, the *SaveFileDialog* only seems to take the local file path with the freely chosen desktop name (**surf**).
The original object name (**surface1**) seems to be overwritten for a further use in my application.
But when I upload the file manually on the website (Frontend), the user interface shows me the original object or surface name like in the CAD program (**surface1**).

(Interesting fact: The code above also results in a successful post/upload with the original object name on the user interface (**surface1**). But when I try to pull the name from `filename.toString().split("/").pop()` I get the desktop name (**surf**) again.)

Where could the webserver get the original object name from? How can I get the original name of the object (**surface1**)?

Don't hesitate to ask for more infos if I was to restrained.
The framework I use is Electron. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Currently, the question is written in a way that makes it hard to understand. Please try to clarify by [edit]ing your post. You said you're using Electron – where does the XHR come into play? (That said, what is your application's architecture? Are you communicating with a backend running on a public webserver?) How are the files "served"? Also, how would you be able to retrieve the previous original filename if you didn't send it to the server? It would be best if you could include a [mcve]. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Alexander! Thank you for your detailed instructions. I hope I was able to clarify my question.

Comment: I see. Well, the website where you upload it probably opens the file and reads the surface's name from the data stored by the CAD in the file. Of course the old filename is lost when you choose an arbitrary name while saving to your Desktop. You'll probably have to inspect the file format used and parse the file in your application in order to retrieve the surface's name.